# Multi select dropdown or picker node module for Nativescript angular project

Tags: android, ios, typescript, nativescript, angular-nativescript

Is there any node NPM module for multi-select dropdown in nativescript Angular. I have gone through most of the plugin in native script marketplace but I could not find the one.

I was looking for the plugin which should be compatible with both Android and iOS.

Comment: I think there is none for multiple selection. But you may just use a ListView with two templates one for normal and another for selected state for this purpose.

Comment: But in my case, I was supposed to use more than 1 multi-select dropdown in a page. I such case using multiple list view makes design complications. Instead, i will try to use list view in a popup and return the selected values.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a dropdown but a gallery picker and it will work if you need to select images.  The [`nativescript-imagepicker`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-imagepicker) comes with two mods: `single` and `multiple`. As far as I remember you need to do a long press to activate the multiselection.

Quote from the plugin's README

> The mode if the imagepicker. Possible values are
>   single for single selection and multiple for multiple selections.